# find() from MongoDB, return result, supress fields and turn into JSON

Tags: ruby, mongodb-query

I Have data saved in a MongoDB in the following format

`{"_id": "VALVE22","state": "1","element": "BNK1FLOW","data":{"type": "SEN","descr": "TOWER6"}}`

I have the following code in a Ruby script;

```
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("cooler-lookup")
coll = db.collection("elements")
kitty = coll.find({"_id" => table[address][i], "state" => char}).to_a
```

`'table[address][i]' and 'char'` are variables defined & used elsewhere in the bigger script feeding data into this lookup section. For testing these can be replaced with "VALVE22" and "1" respectively (and that's how I've been testing in irb)

When run from the command line the script outputs the following correct result from a valid query.

`{"_id"=>"VLAVE22", "state"=>"1", "element"=>"BNK1FLOW", "data"=>{"type"=>"SEN", "descr"=>"TOWER6"}}`

But I need to suppress the `_id and state` fields. I've tried using `:fields` modifier in all sorts of ways but can't remove the fields. I have tested this in irb and along with the valid lookup I also get `=> nil` returned. I'm sure this is something really simple but I can't see what I need to be able to `JSON.generate` the query results without the ID & State fields and then `puts` it.

Using the code below I was able to get this working, however when I tried to do `kittylitter = JSON.generate(kitty)` I was getting a lot of empty `[]`'s as well as my valid result. It looks like they where the failed queries from the DB coming back with no record.

After many hours of being confused I managed to find this bit of code to fix the problem

```
kitty.each do |key|
keyjson = JSON.generate(key)
puts keyjson
end
```

That gave me exactly what I needed out - which was the result on 1 line as valid JSON. Part of my head hurting confusion comes from the fact `to.a` makes an array, yet when I tried to do array type stuff on the result `kitty` nothing would work as expected. I then tried treating it like a hash which led me to that bit of code above! Once I'd done that everything worked... Am I wrong to be confused by arrays and hashes or have I missed something real obvious like my array *is* or *contains* a hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
kitty = coll.find({"_id" => table[address][i], "state" => char}, :fields => {"_id" => 0, "state" => 0}).to_a
```

It returns

```
[{"element"=>"BNK1FLOW", "data"=>{"type"=>"SEN", "descr"=>"TOWER6"}}]
```

See http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method for usage instructions for `Mongo::Collection#find`

Comment: Thanks - not sure what I was doing last night then for it not to work. Maybe spent too long looking at it getting confused. That worked for me, but when I do `kittylitter = JSON.generate(kitty)` I get the desired result BUT I also get lots of empty `[]`'s Is there any way for me to get rid of those?

Comment: @user3788685 - Do you mean empty `{}`'s? Sounds like you have a number of documents that match the query but dont have any keys other than _id and state. Look into Ruby Array#select (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-select)

Comment: When running the script from command line its `[]` I get deffo not `{}` I wondered if it was queries which returned nothing at all. When data is received from `table[address][i]` its actually doing 8 lookup's some, all, or none of them may result in a valid result in the DB. The DB contains only a handful of objects which all have valid & full keys, the things that don't exist don't exist at all in the DB. I have a check of the link you gave - I think I have a `for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++)` type example somewhere in my bigger script so I'll try and knock something up.

Comment: Managed to make it work - I'll update my question with what I did & accept your answer as it sorted the underlying issue :) I got very confused though... `to.a` makes an array - when I tried to do array type stuff it didn't want to work. When I treated it as a hash and did hash stuff it works... How come?!

Answer (score 0):

Using **gem mongo -v 2.4.3** , the following works for me

```
mongo_results = collection.find({"shop_id" => shop_id}, :projection => {"_id" => 0, "child_products" => 0}).to_a
```

In the example above, I'm omitting "_id" and "child_products" from showing up in the results.